# Can ServiceBusProcessorClient receive deferred message or not?

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

I am trying to use  `ServiceBusProcessorClient`  from Azure Service Bus messaging jar (azure-messaging-servicebus-7.1.0). I have seen  `defer`  API on  `ServiceBusReceivedMessageContext` . But did not see any API to retrieve deferred message.  `ServiceBusProcessorClient`  accepts a  `Consumer`  to process message. Can that consumer receive deferred message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The processor client is very high level client and only provides a convenient API to receive and process messages. You have to use lower level client `ServiceBusReceiverClient` or `ServiceBusReceiverAsyncClient` for this and they have exposed much more APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Even the message is deferred, it still [remain in the main queue along with all other active messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-deferral#retrieving-deferred-messages)

We [use ServiceBusProcessorClient to receive the message in the main queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-java-how-to-use-queues#receive-messages-from-a-queue).

So the answer should be yes.